# Regex limiting a number string

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to use regex to pass a 6 digit number string.  My trouble is the string can be any 6 digits, unless it starts with 12.  So the first digit can be 1 but not if second digit is 2.  The second digit can be 2, but not if the first is 1.

I tried this, `([^1])([^2])(\d{4})` but that does not take into account both digits, so it will block anything with a 2 in the second spot.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use [alteration](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^([02-9][0-9]|[0-9][013-9])[0-9]{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p5q1tS/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([02-9][0-9]|[0-9][013-9])` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `[02-9][0-9]` - any digit but 1 and then any digit
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9][013-9]` - any digit and then any digit but `2`
- `[0-9]{4}` - any 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Another way is to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!12)[0-9]{6}$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIgAV7/1). Here, `(?!12)` fails the match if the first 2 digits are `12`. The `[0-9]{6}` will match 6 digits.

Depending on the regex library/method, `^`/`$` anchors may not be required. Lookaheads are not always supported, too.